# Associating test cases with test methods when using [TestClass] rather [CodedUITest]

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, tfs, visual-studio-2017, activityunittestcase

We are using Unit test project for UI automation using selenium web driver.

I can execute test from visual studio Test >Test Explore > Select the Test and Click on Run.

I am not able to Associate the Test case to the Test method From Unit 
Test Project  which were developed in Unit Test project.

We are using Visual Studio 2017 Professional version in this we are able to see the option ‘Associate Test case’ in disable mode ( Test > Test Explore > Right click on any  unit Test method  > Associate To Test case )

Please suggest the solution for associating the Test cases.

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a test project containing your automated test, then build it. See the supported test types: [What types of tests are supported?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/reference-qa#test-types)

Just follow the steps mentioned in this link to sssociate your tests: [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case)

> **Associate your test**
>
> If you know the identifier of the work item for the test case:
>
> 1. If the **Test Explorer** window is not displayed, open it from the **Test
>      | Windows** menu.
> 2. If your tests are not displayed in **Test Explorer**, build the
>      solution.
> 3. In **Test Explorer**, select the test method you want to associate
>      and choose **Associate to Test Case**.
> 4. In the dialog that opens, type the test case identifier and choose
>      **Add Association**, then choose **Save**.
>
> If you do not know the identifier of the work item for the test case:
>
> - Ensure you have configured Visual Studio to display test work items    inside the Visual Studio editor rather than in your web browser. See
>     [Can I configure work items to open in Visual Studio?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/reference-qa#open-in-vs)
> - In **Team Explorer** open the **Work Items** tab. If the **Team Explorer** window    is not displayed, open it from the **View** menu.
> - Expand the list of **Queries** in the **Work Items** tab to find one that    displays your test cases, for example the default **My
>     Test Cases** query. For more information about how to use queries in
>     Team Explorer, see [Use the query editor to list and manage
>     queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries)
> - Execute the query by choosing **View Results** on the shortcut menu (or    double-click the query name).
> - Open the test case you want to associate by choosing **Open** on the    shortcut menu (or double-click the test case name).
> - In the work item, open the **ASSOCIATED AUTOMATION** tab. All the tests    in the solution are shown in the list together with their
>     associated    test projects.
> - Choose the ellipsis (**...**) and, in the **Choose Test** dialog, select the    test and then choose OK. The value in **Automation
>     Status** is    automatically changed to **Automated**.
> - Choose **Save Work Item** to save the changes to the test case.
>
> Source link : [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case)

Comment: @satish vegi Is the answer help for you? If that resolved your issue, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.